# Way to initialize synthesizable 2D array with constant values in Verilog

Tags: arrays, initialization, constants, vhdl, verilog

in VHDL, I can easily do this:

```
constant    cmdbytes       : bytearray(0 to Total) := (x"05", x"00", x...};
```

I want synthesizable constants so that when the FPGA starts, this array has the data I supplied.  These registers are wired to VCC or ground to represent 1 or 0.  I can then use them to generate a waveform.  Also I would like to have 2D byte array which is 3D in verilog world.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're just using the array to pull out one value at a time, how about using a `case` statement? Granted, it's a long-winded way of doing it, but you could always write a script to write the RTL for you.

```
reg [7:0] value;
reg [7:0] i;

always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin
    if(!rst_n)
        i <= 8'd0;
    else
        i <= i + 1;
end

always @(*) begin
    case(i) 
        8'h00: value = 8'd0;
        8'h01: value = 8'd34;
        ...
    endcase
endcase
```

Another way is to use an `initial` statement. As far as I'm aware, FPGA synthesis tools will allow you to set initial values for arrays in the following manner. Again, a script to write this may be the way to go.

```
reg [0:35][7:0] my_array;

initial begin
    my_array[0] = 8'd45;
    my_array[1] = 8'd26;
    ...
end
```

And if your FGPA synthesis tools support some SystemVerilog, you'll be able to initialise the array like so:

```
reg [0:34][7:0] my_array = '{ 8'd90, 8'd34, ... }; // note the '{
```

Answer (score 1):

```
module test (

   input [7:0]   p1_sa,            // i
   input [7:0]   p1_sb,            // i
   output [7:0]   p3,            // o
   output [7:0]   p3b            // o
);

logic [7:0] array2d [7:0] = {99,124,119,123,242,107,111,197};

   assign p3    = array2d[p1_sa];
   assign p3b   = array2d[p1_sb];

endmodule
```

I tried the above system verilog code and it is working fine in modelsim and Vivado.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the `case` statement approach is to use a `function` to access values.

Example for an "array" of size 4 containing 8 bit constants:

```
function [7:0] cmdbytes;
        input    [1:0] index;
        reg      [7:0] t[0:3];
    begin
        {   
             t[0],t[1],t[2],t[3]
        } = {   
             8'h05, 8'h00, 8'h5b, 8'h45
        };

        cmdbytes = t[index];
    end
endfunction
```

One can access the constants like so:

```
wire [7:0] value0;
wire [7:0] value1;
wire [7:0] value2;
wire [7:0] value3;

assign value0 = cmdbytes(2'd0);
assign value1 = cmdbytes(2'd1);
assign value2 = cmdbytes(2'd2);
assign value3 = cmdbytes(2'd3);
```

Answer (score -1):

Verilog 2005 doesn't allow array initialization. Though your FPGA vendor should have a means to generate a ROM.