# 2D Arrays in Verilog

Tags: arrays, verilog

I have defined

```
reg bricks[0:3][0:7]
```

in Verilog Module.
How can I assign this 2d array as

```
{{1,1,1,0,1,1,1},{1,1,1,0,1,1,1},{1,1,1,0,1,1,1},{1,1,1,0,1,1,1}}.
```

Please help

Comment: Assign it how? As a default value, or during operation?

Comment: Are you sure you want a 2d array of bits, and not a 1d array of a multi-bit value? e.g. `reg [7:0] bricks[0:3]`

Comment: [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130181/way-to-initialize-synthesizable-2d-array-with-constant-values-in-verilog) covers some of what you are asking. As mentioned there you cannot do a direct initialization the way you mentioned in verilog. But tools that synthesize system verilog might support the format you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
reg bricks [0:3][0:7];     //creates an unpacked array 
                           // It means you can access individual bits

bricks[1][0] = 0 ;         // Assigns 0 to the bit referenced by 1 and 0 

bricks [2] = 0 ;           // Illegal Syntax

bricks [1][0:3] = 0 ;      //Illegal Syntax
```

System verilog provides much more flexibility