# Can I assign variables to multidimensional array elements in verilog?

Tags: verilog

Can I assign something like this in Verilog:

```
reg [4:0] synd[0:4]={s0,s1,s2,s3,s4};//s0,s1,s2....s4 are 5 bit values.
```

Also, while accessing this array from inside the 'always' block, should I just reference it as say synd[0] for s0 and so on?

Comment: in verilog -- no, in system verilog -- yes (just a bit different syntax). In any case such initialization of variables is not synthesizable. In the code you use synd[index] to access the array.

Comment: Syntax in SystemVerilog is exactly correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Way to initialize synthesizable 2D array with constant values in Verilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130181/way-to-initialize-synthesizable-2d-array-with-constant-values-in-verilog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verilog does not allow for more than 1-D array. However systemverilog allows such construct and it is syntactically correct according to systemverilog.